# Swift multiple cells in one UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a simple messaging app. I want to display user and expert messages left and right side of screen like WhatsApp. So I created 2 xib for do this. However, I dont know the how I am going to use 'cellForRowAt' to display messages to screen.

**There is what I am trying up to now:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        for i in 0..<generalMessageArray.count{

            if generalMessageArray[i].mType == "U"{
                let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MessageUserTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MessageUserTableViewCell
                cell.lblMessage.text = generalMessageArray[indexPath.row].message
                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MessageExpertTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MessageExpertTableViewCell
                cell.lblMessage.text = generalMessageArray[indexPath.row].message
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()

    }
```

But it didn't work in right way. When debug comes in for loop value of 'i' doesn't increase because of 'return cell' but i don't know what am I doing.

Comment: It really looks like you skipped many tutorials and basic iOS stuff... I highly recommend you to follow any UITableView tutorial you can find out there http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/ or https://theswiftdev.com/2018/12/01/uitableview-tutorial-in-swift/ for example

Comment: you should know tableview for single cell before proceeding  to complex ui . Better learn delegate methods of tableview first . Link provided by @Kalzem are good source , you can look .

Answer (score -1):

Might be you are looking for below custom UITableView and source code;

```
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/scroller
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/animated-tableviewcell    
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stbubbletableviewcell    
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ptsmessagingcell    
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsmessagesviewcontroller   
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sphchatbubble
```

Use and edit it as per your requirement.